# Remove the parenthesis in the output

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to do this except without the parenthesis in the output? The API that takes the output can't deal with them.

```
select a,b,c,d,e from (select n_dead_tup from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'table1') as a, 
(select n_dead_tup from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'table2') as b, 
(select n_dead_tup from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'table3') as c, 
(select n_dead_tup from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'table4') as d, 
(select n_dead_tup from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'table5') as e;
```

This output is something like this:

```
 a        |     b     |    c     |     d     |     e     
----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------
(7781834) | (7781834) | (483464) | (1426296) | (5452406)
```

Comment: I'm not super proficient with Postgres, but you should be able to convert your output to a string and perform some string manipulation (i.e. replace `(` and `)` with `''`, the empty string)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are selecting *tuples* via the table name rather than columns.  You will see this if you select `a.n_dead_tup` instead.  You can repeat this for all the tables, if you like, but I prefer the solutions below.

I would suggest a simple `group by`:

```
select relname, n_dead_tup
from pg_stat_user_tables
where relname in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5');
```

Or conditional aggregation:

```
select max(n_dead_tup) filter (relname = 'table1') as table1,
       max(n_dead_tup) filter (relname = 'table2') as table2,
       max(n_dead_tup) filter (relname = 'table3') as table3,
       max(n_dead_tup) filter (relname = 'table4') as table4,
       max(n_dead_tup) filter (relname = 'table5') as table5
from pg_stat_user_tables
where relname in ('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The output needs to be in columns like I showed in the original post, yours seem to output a list.

Comment: @kernel-trick . . . The last query puts the results in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Regex replace would probably be the simplest approach:

```
regexp_replace(a, '\(|\)', '', 'g');
```

You need the pipe in there for either left or right paren, and as a result, you'll need to escape the parens with the slashes. The g is a flag to remove all examples of them from the string